# Raspbian technique to connect to any strong open wifi signals?

Tags: raspbian, networking

My Pi is going to be mobile, is there an easy way to headlessly ping and connect to the strongest open wifi connection it finds?  Are there programs for this?  I'm having trouble seeing any..

Should I switch to a distro like Kali linux instead?

Comment: Have you looked at this as a starting point for connections? http://weworkweplay.com/play/automatically-connect-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-wifi-network/

Comment: I saw that, but it assumes I'll know the SSID ahead of time.  I'm looking for automatic scanning, detection, and attempt to connect.